# Передача даных в унаследованый класc JS

Tags: javascript

Ребят никак немогу понять где у меня ошыбка, почемуто всегда выдает undefined поетому обращаюсь за помощю

```js
class Persons {
  constructor(firstName, lastName, age, email) {

    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
    this.email = email;
    this.done = false;

  }
  toString() {
    this.done = true;
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + "(age: " + this.age + ", email: " + this.email + ")";
  }
}

class Alcohol extends Persons {
  constructor(firstName, age) {
    super(firstName, age);

  }
  toString() {
    this.done = true;
    return this.age >= 18 ? "Name: " + this.firstName + " sell" : "Name: " + this.firstName + " not sell";
  }


}

let personPersons = new Persons('Maria', 'Petrova', 17, 'mp@yahoo.com');
let personAlcohol = new Alcohol();
console.log(personPersons.toString());
console.log(personAlcohol.toString());
```

Comment: Конструктор у тебя ожидает две переменных, а ты ничего не передаешь. Вывод?

Comment: да я понимаю но если я передаю то не отрабатывает условие, можно для примера исправить, так будет понятней, спасибо?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, конструктор `Alcohol` принимает два параметра `(firstName, age)`, значит их нужно передать: `let personAlcohol = new Alcohol('Maria', 17);`

Во-вторых, в дочернем классе вы вызываете конструктор родительского, передавая 2 параметра вместо необходимых 4-х `(firstName, lastName, age, email)`, из-за этого получается, что `this.age = undefined`. Поскольку в дочернем классе вам не нужна вся информация, то достаточно вызвать `super(firstName, null, age);`

```js
class Persons {
  constructor(firstName, lastName, age, email) {

    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
    this.email = email;
    this.done = false;

  }
  toString() {
    this.done = true;
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + "(age: " + this.age + ", email: " + this.email + ")";
  }
}

class Alcohol extends Persons {
  constructor(firstName, age) {
    super(firstName, null, age);

  }
  toString() {
    this.done = true;
    return this.age >= 18 ? "Name: " + this.firstName + " sell" : "Name: " + this.firstName + " not sell";
  }


}

let personPersons = new Persons('Maria', 'Petrova', 17, 'mp@yahoo.com');
let personAlcohol = new Alcohol('Maria', 17);
console.log(personPersons.toString());
console.log(personAlcohol.toString());
```

Чтобы не приходилось пропускать параметры для родительского класса, можно передавать в конструктор объект.

```js
class Persons {
    constructor({firstName, lastName, age, email}) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
        this.email = email;
        this.done = false;
    }
    toString() {
        this.done = true;
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + "(age: " + this.age + ", email: " + this.email + ")";
    }
}

class Alcohol extends Persons {
    constructor(options) {
        super(options);
    }
    toString() {
        this.done = true;
        return this.age >= 18 ? "Name: " + this.firstName + " sell" : "Name: " + this.firstName + " not sell";
    }
}

let personPersons = new Persons({
    firstName: 'Maria',
    lastName: 'Petrova',
    age: 17,
    email: 'mp@yahoo.com'
});
let personAlcohol = new Alcohol({
    firstName: 'Maria',
    age: 17
});
console.log(personPersons.toString());
console.log(personAlcohol.toString());
```

Comment: большое спасибо, всё понятно!

Comment: Если вас устроил мой ответ, отметьте его пожалуйста в качестве решения